Can't extract in /usr/share/icons/
I was trying to extract a file in /usr/share/icons but it said I don't have the right permissions to extract in /usr/share/icons. I also can't paste in /usr/share/icons. I think the problem is that I need to grant myself the right permissions, but I don't know how. Is there a way to fix this?

You need to use sudo.

You have to use sudo, that is correct.
If you want to actually change the permissions, so you don't need the password:
sudo chown -R username:username /usr/share/icons

-R applies ownership to everything in that directory, recursively.
Change the username to your user account's name.
It's icons, so you'll need it recursive.

I got an error saying : chown: cannot access '/usr/share/icon': No such file or directory, I think the command is wrong.

@ProGaming It's icons, with an s.

Thank you, it worked. I had to replace username: with nothing but my user name. But still, thanks

@ProGaming Excellent.  The first one is user permissions, the second is for group.  (i.e. user:group) Type: chown --help, It will immediately make sense.
